# Read logs from Application Insights Using C#

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, azureportal

I am trying to read logs from Application Insights in Azure Portal. I know how to create them but I am trying to figure out a way that I can read them so that I can confirm that a process is running correctly in unit testing.

Would any one know how to do this or have any articles they can point me to?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://zimmergren.net/retrieve-logs-from-application-insights-programmatically-with-net-core-c/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/get

Answer (score 0):

To get a much richer representation of the exception with additional contextual information, stack trace and custom data that you decide to include with your error message
And also, to get the exception logging with custom events in the detailed format,

Follow the steps provided in this documentation [logging-with-application-insights](https://dzimchuk.net/tracing-and-logging-with-application-insights/)